# Adding url and alt attributes dynamically with radio buttons in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I have a group of radio buttons that are built dynamically using a JSON file.  The JSON file contains things like url (of an image), alt text, etc...

I have it working pretty well, and can change the value of the img src based on the value of the radio button selected.  However, what if I need to access other elements of the json object as well so that I can set the alt text of the image depending on the element selected.

Here is a plunkr of the basic functionality as I have it to this point...

http://plnkr.co/edit/bI4ggTNCPSq3o1Bt6gqg?p=preview

The JSON object looks like so:

```
{
    "header_images" : [
        {
            "id" : "havoc-header",
            "alt" : "Some alt text",
            "fname" : "admissions-general-havoc-header.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/admissions-general-havoc-header.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id" : "cob-header",
            "alt" : "Some more alt text",
            "fname" : "cob-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/cob-banner.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id" : "css-header",
            "alt" : "still some more alt text",
            "fname" : "css-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/css-banner.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id" : "huns-header",
            "alt" : "one more alt-text",
            "fname" : "huns-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/huns-banner.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

The radio buttons are being built in the view like so:

```
<label ng-repeat="header in assets.header_images">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="assets.headerimage" value="{{header.url}}" id="{{header.id}}" data-alt="{{header.alt}}" />
    {{header.url}}
</label>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/assets.json').then(function(res){
        $scope.assets = res.data;
    });
}
```

So basically when a radio button is clicked, I would like to populate this which is outside of the ng-repeat:

```
 <img src="{{assets.headerimage}}" alt="{{alt}}" />
```

The src attribute is easy enough.  I have that working fine...As you can see when one of the dynamic radio buttons are checked, the value is added to the assets.headerimage binding. But, how would I set the appropriate alt text?

I am sure this is really easy, but I can't get my head around it for some reason.  I am relatively new to angularjs, so be gentle :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ng-change` event in the `input`. Assume the `alt` is in the `parent` scope, and then you can use `$parent` to access `alt`

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="assets.headerimage" ng-change="$parent.alt = header.alt" ... >
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as correct because it is the answer that got me there, but not exactly correct.  Basically ng-change="assets.alt = header.alt"  I have been told you shouldn't use $parent because it is kind of hackey.  And then in the image I am just setting to alt="{{assets.alt}}"

Comment: @kevindeleon Though `$parent` is undocumented, people use it all the time. It is a very neat way to access the data in the parent scope from child scope.

Comment: I see.  I have used it in the past, but have just seen several people say that defining the model in your controller using an object instead of a primitive and then using dot syntax is a more robust solution and less prone to breakage.

Answer (score 4):

in your radio `ng-model`, you are assigning `header.url` to the model, so you cant access the `alt`. but instead if you assign the `header` to the model you will be able to access the `alt`.

```
<label ng-repeat="header in assets.header_images">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="assets.headerimage" value="{{header}}" id="{{header.id}}" data-alt="{{header.alt}}" />
</label>

 <img ng-src="{{assets.headerimage.url}}" alt="{{assets.headerimage.alt}}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry...I see how this was unclear...I will edit my question, but basically that image is the label...when the radio button changes, we will be editing ANOTHER image on the page...not the one inside the ng-repeat...that would have been too easy right!? haha.

Comment: ok,,, but the answer is almost the same, whenever you select a radio, it will assign the value to the model, so you can access the model anywhere within the scope.

Comment: It may be simple, but I don't think this works.  I am under the impression that the value of an input can only be a string, not an object.

Comment: you are right, @Kevindeleon, the `assets.headerimage` output a json string, but `assets.headerimage.url` output nothing. it is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a side-note, you should use `ng-src` ([link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc)) for populating source of an image. This way your browser will not hit 404s after request wrong URLs like `/{{assets.headerimage}}`.

Now, regarding your question. Assuming your `id` is unique, you could re-work your JSON to a form similar to this:

```
{
    "header_images" : {
        "havoc-header": {
            "id" : "havoc-header",
            "alt" : "Some alt text",
            "fname" : "admissions-general-havoc-header.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/admissions-general-havoc-header.jpg"
        },
        "cob-header": {
            "id" : "cob-header",
            "alt" : "Some more alt text",
            "fname" : "cob-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/cob-banner.jpg"
        },
        "css-header": {
            "id" : "css-header",
            "alt" : "still some more alt text",
            "fname" : "css-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/css-banner.jpg"
        },
        "huns-header": {
            "id" : "huns-header",
            "alt" : "one more alt-text",
            "fname" : "huns-banner.jpg",
            "url" : "email-assets/header-images/huns-banner.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

then change `value="{{header.url}}"` of each of your checkboxes to `value="{{header.id}}"`, and finally populate your image like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ assets.header_images[assets.headerimage].url }}"/>
```

Another way does not require modifying the JSON structure, but it still involves using `header.id` as your model's value. Simply add a function like this to your scope:

```
$scope.getChosenHeader = function() {
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.header_images.length;i++) {
        var h = $scope.header_images[i];
        if(h.id === $scope.assets.headerimage) {
            return h;
        }
    }
}
```

and then populate your image like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ getChosenHeader().url }}"/>
```

This way you can access the whole object instead of just `url` property. Of course remember to only show your `<img/>` tag if `getChosenHeader().url` is not undefined